# Android/WiFi Direct - how find pc with the smartphone and establish a connection

Tags: android-wifi, wifi-direct

I want develop a simple program for an Android smartphone that give the possibility to the user to transfer an image from the device to the pc. I want create a direct connection using the WiFi Direct technology. I saw the official documentation on the developer android site, and i found it very helpful. My question now, is how can i find the pc and established a connection with it? I saw that establish a connection from two smartphone is really easy, but how can i proceed in this case? The pc need to be in a wireless network (i don't think) ?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @AdrianWragg For the moment i have already implemented the code to transfer the images (i'm using a server for the moment), but i ask this only for understand what i have to do in the pc side. Have i to install a driver or something? Have i to change something in the wireless settings of the pc? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PC does not need to be on a wireless network (that is the whole point of using Wifi-Direct) but to enable Wifi-Direct on a PC, you need to install the Intel MyWifi Dashboard software (full version) and also need to make sure that your drivers are updated. 
(http://www.intel.com/support/notebook/sb/CS-033660.htm)